# Send users back to login page if ftp authentication fails php

Tags: php, ftp

I am creating a ftp editor on my site where users can edit their site.

Curruntly, I am working on the login page of my ftp editor, I want to redirect user back to the login page if something goes wrong with ftp authentication.

Here is my open_ftp.php

```
 $ftp_server=$_POST["fsvr"];
$usr=$_POST["uname"];
$pass=$_POST["pwd"];
$ftp_con=ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect");
$login=ftp_login($ftp_con,$usr,$pass);

if(empty($login))
 {header('location : /login.php');}
```

If I enter the wrong ftp user name or authentication fails ,then it should redirect me back to login page, but it's not happening here, My open_ftp.php shows error **authentication faild** (error from php) but my page is not redirecting.

Is something wrong with my php?

Comment: Well, it is not `empty()` but `FALSE` when the login is not correct (see [their documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php))

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment, change the code as follows. Additionally, it is good practice to have an `exit()` after a redirection call:

```
$ftp_server = $_POST["fsvr"];
$usr = $_POST["uname"];
$pass = $_POST["pwd"];
$ftp_con = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect");
if (($login = ftp_login($ftp_con, $usr, $pass)) === FALSE) {
    header("Location : /login.php");
    exit();
}
```